# Насколько реально подобрать токен бота в телеграм?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Насколько реально взломать бота в Telegram, подобрав токен?

Comment: Вполне реально, надеюсь вы располагаете свободным временем, думаю пары миллиардов лет будет достаточно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The token looks something like `123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11`

Грубо говоря, понадобится где-то 8×10⁵⁶ попыток. Вряд ли в самом алгоритме генерации есть какая-то уязвимость.